# Django not posting values from database

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am a beginner at django and python. I am trying to post values from the database to my html template but not able to do so
Here is my models file

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

    `from django.db import models

    `class post(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
        body = models.TextField()
        date = models.DateTimeField()`
        `from django.db import models`

    urls file

        `from django.conf.urls import url,include
    from . import views
    from django.contrib.auth.views import login
    from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
    from personal.models import post`

    `urlpatterns = [

        url(r'^projects/',views.projects, name='projects'),`

       views.py file

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import post
from personal.models import post

def projects(request):
    return render(request,'personal/projects.html')
```

while this created a table personal_post in mysql when i reference it in my template projects.html by {{post.title}} or {{projects_post.title}}, it does not return any value. ]

Also i have used python the hard way and django unleashed 2017 as part of learning django, any other books for comprehension

Comment: Can you share your views.py code as well? You are probably not passing the context from the projects(...) method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `posts` as a variable in the context to the view, inorder to render it on the template.

Try this,

```
def projects(request): 
    posts = post.objects.all()
    return render(request,'personal/projects.html', {'posts' : posts })
```

And in your template,

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

For rendering variables from view to the template, you need to pass a context, which is a dictionary with keys as their name and values as the contents of the variable.

Check out the documentation for more about `render` function and context [here...](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#render)